# macos 10.12 upgrade to icu4c 67.1 failed

Tags: macos, homebrew, icu4c

I'm using a older iMac which can't upgrade macos to above 10.12.
When I do brew upgrade fontforge, it failed at upgraded fontforge dependency icu4c.  Following is partial log.

Googling didn't return much information, any one had similar issue and know how to resolve it ?

```
==> Installing fontforge dependency: icu4c
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1 --disable-samples --disable-tests --enable-static --with-library-bits=64
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/erickung/Library/Logs/Homebrew/icu4c/02.make:
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -DU_HAVE_STRING_VIEW=1 -I. -I../common -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wglobal-constructors -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT msgfmt.d msgfmt.o msgfmt.ao -o msgfmt.ao msgfmt.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [msgfmt.ao] Error 1
3 errors generated.
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -DU_HAVE_STRING_VIEW=1 -I. -I../common -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wglobal-constructors -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT decimfmt.d decimfmt.o decimfmt.ao -o decimfmt.ao decimfmt.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [decimfmt.ao] Error 1
3 errors generated.
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -DU_HAVE_STRING_VIEW=1 -I. -I../common -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wglobal-constructors -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT numfmt.d numfmt.o numfmt.ao -o numfmt.ao numfmt.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [numfmt.ao] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

These open issues may also help:
icu4c 67.1 (make C++14 compatible) https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/59540
```

Comment: Same problem on macOS 10.12.6 when installing node@12, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems like there's a branch with updated formula for this lib: https://github.com/dotysan/homebrew-core/tree/icu4c-cplusplus14 , I was able to install it cloning the branch (you can actually download only the needed formula) and pointing brew to this version explicitly:

```
git clone https://github.com/dotysan/homebrew-core/
cd homebrew-core/
git checkout -b icu4c-cplusplus14 origin/icu4c-cplusplus14
brew reinstall --build-from-source ./Formula/icu4c.rb
```